# How do I get MouseEventArgs.Source as the TextBox when defined inside TabControl.ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, prism

I am using `prism` `InvokeCommandAction` to bind the `Window.PreviewMouseDown` to the `MainWindowViewModel`. I then have a `TabControl` whose `ItemsSource` is bounded to an `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>` and the `TabControl.ContentTemplate` to the `ItemViewModel.ItemContent`.

The issue is that when the `ItemViewModel.ItemContent` is/has a `TextBox` and is clicked, the `MouseEventArgs.Source` is the `TabControl`.

I would like the `MouseEventArgs.Source` to be the `TextBox` which is what happens when I just bind to a `ContentControl.Content` outside of a `TabControl.ContentTemplate`.

Below is code for repro:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SingleItemContent}" />
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemViewModels}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ItemContent}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            PreviewMouseDownCommand = new DelegateCommand<MouseEventArgs>(PreviewMouseDown);

            PopulateItems();
        }

        public ICommand PreviewMouseDownCommand { get; }

        private void PreviewMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            /// if SingleItemContent is clicked
            /// e.Source is TextBox

            /// if an ItemViewModel.ItemContent is clicked
            /// e.Source is TabControl
        }

        private void PopulateItems()
        {
            ItemViewModels.Add(new ItemViewModel
            {
                ItemContent = new TextBox()
            });

            SingleItemContent = new TextBox();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemViewModels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        public object SingleItemContent { get; set; }
    }
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public object ItemContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check the e.OriginalSource ? and find parent TextBox, or use MouseDown instead of PreviewMouseDown

Comment: You shouldn't create and reference TextBox controls in a view model...this breaks the MVVM pattern. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @IlyaGrigoryan I'll try your suggestions Thanks!

Comment: @mm8 I'm generating wpf controls based on an xml file to recreate a certain screen. The controls are part of my domain so it doesn't break the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @PaoloGo: Then you might as well handle the PreviewMouseDown event of the TextBox controls themselves.